# Change items in database based on an array of values in Python Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, put

I have a string of values being posted to my python API

```
["7779987","5559098","2453987"]
```

these numbers are unique identifiers of users in my database. These users have an 'amount' tuple. What I want to do is, when the array is received, in my code, I get all the users that have their IDs in the string and subtract 10 from their current amount value.

This is what I tried but I know I'm doing something wrong. How do I go about this?

```
class PayForTrips(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)

        for index_number in request.data:
            print(index_number + "; ")
            user = User.objects.get(index_number=index_number)
            print("old user amount" + str(user.amount))
            user.amount -= 10
            print("new user amount" + str(user.amount))
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)// here is where the problem is
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

EDIT: I'm new to Django so I don't know how to go about this. If my code is completely wrong, could you show me how to go about achieving this?

EDIT: @Daniel Roseman 's solution solved the problem. This is the code that works:

```
class PayForTrips(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)

        for index_number in request.data:
            print(index_number + "; ")
            user = User.objects.get(index_number=index_number)

            print(user)
            print("old user amount" + str(user.amount))
            user.amount -= 1
            print("new user amount" + str(user.amount))
            user.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @FamousJameous I'm able to get the users from the database but I think the `(data=user)` part is wrong because it doesn't save the updated amount in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of the serializer here? There doesn't seem to be any reason to use one. You've already got the items and modified their amount; all you need to do is to save them.

The other issue is that you return inside your loop; you need to move that final line out of the loop, and then return a list of the IDs that you successfully updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass many=True para to serializer, and custom a UsersSerializer to receive and validate user_ids is a good way. Finally, use F to update users.

```
    from django.db.models import F
    class UsersSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            queryset=User.objects.all(),
            many=True   #many=True to receive multi ids.
        )

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UsersSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        users = serializer.data.get('users') #since I use PrimaryKeyRelatedField, serializer.data actually returns user instances.
        users = users.update(amount = F('amount')-10)
        return　Responce(UserSerializer(users, many=True).data) #notice, do not use data=users, since user is an instance.

    and post json data: {"users":[7779987,5559098,...]}
```